# Got stuck how to insert previous date and time

Tags: oracle

how to insert previous day date,and time. (i am using Date datatype)
Time is - 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract `1` from date value; doing so, you'd subtract `1` day.

Setting format (so that you'd know what is what):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate right_now,
  2         sysdate - 1 yesterday,
  3         trunc(sysdate - 1) yesterday_midnight
  4  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           YESTERDAY           YESTERDAY_MIDNIGHT
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
14.03.2022 11:16:14 13.03.2022 11:16:14 13.03.2022 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Comment: hi, can you suggest to me some good books, playlist or course to learn oracle database

Comment: I learnt it by reading official Oracle documentation.

Comment: My question is 'SQL query to select the ENTRY_TIME hour,count of records in that hour from table WIQ_MSG_MIS_030213' i have pasted my table below,have a look!!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJhsn.png

Comment: That's an ordinary `SELECT TO_CHAR (e_time, 'hh24') AS hour, COUNT (*) FROM wiq_msg_mis_030213 GROUP BY TO_CHAR (e_time, 'hh24')` query

Comment: you're like magician to me

Comment: hello, do you have skype? on any other? we can be connected...you can trust me, i am a simple guy and won't disturb you at anytime.

Comment: Sorry, but this (participating in discussions on Stack Overflow) is the only way I'd like to use to communicate with other people.

Comment: no issue, please don't mind

Comment: hi i want to join 3 tables with count of records .. how to do this? i want to know the syntax for this question

Comment: You should open a **new question** for each new problem you have.

Comment: I just want your suggestions, everything from your side is on point